# Only providing social logins

Tags: login, registration, social-media

I'm currently working on a project where the user is required to register, and we are considering only providing social logins, and not providing a site only registration.

The reason behind this is that the data we will be storing for the user is trivial, and the only sensitive thing would be email and password. However if we use social logins this data is handled for us by the 3rd parties.

This means that we would not need to purchase a SSL Certificate for the website and save money on something that is a hobby/passion project.

We believe if we provide a decent spread of social logins that 99% of the audience will be covered anyway. We are also mindful not to overload the user with too many choices, so were thinking of providing:
Facebook, Google+, Twitter, Microsoft

Would this cause a negative effect on sign up rate?
Are these sites the optimum 4 to reduce overload, but cover the audience?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12300/social-login-adoption-vs-traditional-login related to the topic.

Comment: Also related: [Should we restrict signup for a service to Facebook accounts only?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11965/should-we-restrict-signup-for-a-service-to-facebook-accounts-only)

Comment: I think inevitably, by eschewing the traditional username/password option you may miss out on users. However, if this is a passion project and you feel that the profile of your users are likely to be comfortable using social login, then it's probably not worth your time/cost implementing it.

Comment: @Midas, the development side is not really the issue, it's the cost of the SSL Certificate that is our major concern.

Comment: I hate Social Logins. Take that for what it's worth; probably not much. Only **IF** the site offers compelling functionality and usefulness would I consider using a social account. On that note, I log into the StackExchange sites via Google.

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89, nowadays you can have an SSL certificate for free, check out for example [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)

Comment: There's also [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/), which offers free certificates. Please don't use unencrypted HTTP at this point, it's bordering on irresponsible not to use HTTPS these days.

Comment: Recently i had to create a facebook account to use an online service. I dont have a facebook account and I never use my google account for anything. I personally like signing up with email even tho social logins provide more security because only the token can be stolen but not the password itself.

Comment: I agree with most of your statement except for the "social logins provide more security" part. If someone discovers a person's Facebook credentials then they immediately have access to a slew of other accounts.

Comment: If you do not store any user data why you do need login at all?

Comment: @talex we store data regarding trivial things for our site. Nothing personal or sensitive though.

Comment: I think it's also important to note that for a user, the opposite of not using Social Logins is the amassing of a huge number of separate logins (you're using different passwords for each site, right @MonkeyZeus ...?)

Comment: @adelphus Heck no. If I don't care about the site and only signed up to use it once then you can bet all of your money and assets that I've entered fake information and used some derivative of a blanket password which usually follows {Upper-letter}{word}{numbers}{special char}. I will use entirely unique passwords for services which I care about: email, banking, bills, gaming services. With social auth, this option is not available. I also keep track of these accounts and go through a spring cleaning once a year.

Comment: @JonasDralle I forgot to tag you in my previous comment about "social logins provide more security"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you dont owe me. Facebook isn't impenetratable but it's more secure than when 1 password is shattered over 1000 servers. Then it's easier to obtain the password. Password recycling is just horrible

Comment: This [question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/91712/why-did-ecommerce-registration-rate-go-down-at-checkout-when-we-tested-social) may also offer some useful insights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your specific question on which social logins to use, it depends on your users/market.

[However, Facebook is by far and away the most important one, followed by Google. Then a mix of Twitter, LinkedIn and Yahoo.](http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/most-popular-social-logins-infographic)

[image]

Comment: I'd love to know which type of sites were tested to get to this result.

Comment: It is first party data - from Gigya's clients in that timeframe. The link shows broken down into industry types.

Comment: I think it is also important to realize people use their social networks for different things. I use facebook only for friends and family things thus I will **never** use facebook to log into anything tech or work related... And if a service is not explicitly clear that they are **NOT** requesting the "post on your behalf" permission it is an instant no go.

Comment: Nice graph, do they have a recent one?

Comment: This graph (from its caption) appears to be percentages *of third-party login providers* and doesn't include people logging in directly or ignoring your site because they'd be logging in with facebook.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure about data on desktop design, but I can say that for mobile devices, people will often use the social media login option when it is presented.

[This article](http://www.creativebloq.com/mobile/10-mobile-behaviours-and-designing-them-81412606) about mobile interaction and behavior tells us the following:

> **SOCIAL LOGIN**: While roughly half of the people who participate in our research say they don't like – or want – to make use of social login for various reasons, close to 80 per cent will do it just to avoid the extra typing.

Maybe someone else can provide some information about desktop usage, I've got a feeling that many people don't want to use it because they feel they are giving you insight in their entire private life, even though this might not at all be the case. This is just speculation though.

I would however **NOT** remove the regular option to register, this is most definitively going to cost you conversions, signups, logins, or what ever it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: 80-20 is here again:)

Answer (score 2):

If you wish me to log into your site from work, you need to provide a way for me to do it without risking my Google or Facebook password.      I may not trust my employer to not be spying on me.

There are also a small number of people that don’t have an account on Facebook etc, or who does don’t remain logged in and will not type there “important” password into a popup on your site.

Comment: I have a Facebook account for just the logins on various sites, I don't do anything at all with that account. It is an easy enough solution to decouple my social media use from logins. Uhm, wait ... I don't *have* a "real" Facebook account anyway.