# Some stats about social networks used by iOS/Android users?

Tags: mobile, android, ios, statistics, social

Are there some info and statistics about the social networks used by iOS / Androis users?

If my app will be present in App Store and Google Play, I'd like to distinguish the login methods, the social buttons, etc. depending on it.

Example:
iOS users uses more Facebook: I'll show Facebook button first.
Android users uses more Twitter: I'll ask them to login with Twitter.

Comment: Unless space is a problem why not offer both - I haven't seen any studies about social network usage on particular mobile platforms but I'd bet that the difference is negligible as the networks deliberately try to appeal to *all* users. By the way - I'd also offer the more classical login (email/password) for those users who don't have or don't like to use social logins.

Comment: yes, sure! it0's a good idea to offer both. but for example: if I'm gonna show some alert like "follow me on twitter" or "like my page on facebook", I'd like to show them in some particular order depending on the stats (that I think don't exist :D )

Comment: In that case you might be better off looking for general usage stats comparing each network rather than each platform - most popular login form / network goes first

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.statista.com/statistics/272014/global-social-networks-ranked-by-number-of-users/

Comment: Facebook is the most important option by miles http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/most-popular-social-logins-infographic http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93288/only-providing-social-logins/93292#93292

Comment: My hunch would be that it is significantly more correlated with the country and age of the user rather than their use of iOS or Android.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016 the number of US users of the Facebook app has reached 47 million a month on iOS and 55 million on Android. Facebook is the most popular app on iOS and it is only number 3 on Android.

More info here: http://www.businessofapps.com/facebook-app-statistics/

If the user signed in with social network X, show him alert "follow me on X". It's all about personalization.